# Why is my CSS style sheet not applying to my HTML document?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I think I did everything right. The site is robotichive3774.com if you want to see a tangible version of the website. I am making this site for my school robotics team. Obviously I am an amateur so any other tips would be fantastic.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar">
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="/Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Team Bio">Team Bio</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Our Robot">Our Robot</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Our Coach">Our Coach</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Outreach">Outreach</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Youtube">Youtube</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code

```
li  
{
float: left;
display:inline-block;
}

.nav 
{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden; 
min-width: 1350px;  
}

a:link, a:visited 
{
display:inline-block;
width: 182.2px;
padding-top: 12px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
padding-left: 5px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #990000; 
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active 
{
background-color: #B20000;
}
```

Comment: Is the `index_style.css` file in the same directory as the html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive is

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
```

not

```
<link rel="style sheet"
```

Documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.3.2

Comment: I was able to fiddle your website, and get it to work.

Comment: Nothing - See this: http://jsfiddle.net/36930fkh/ - exactly your code.  Just remove the space, save the file, and force refresh the webpage

Comment: I am not understanding. I removed the space from the "style sheet" and saved the file. I then transferred the files to the server. The site, as you can see, still is not applying the style sheet.

Comment: Wow..... sorry the session for the web server timed out so I never had connection. Sorry about that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="index_style.css">
```

instead of

```
<link rel="style sheet" type="text/css" href="index_style.css">
```

With no space in the rel="style sheet"

Comment: Ok. I changed it but still no luck. Thank you for pointing that out though.